# How two ways--site permissions for one user

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

We're using O365. One user name has two ways site permission. Why and how happened that

[image]

NB:

We have checked AD and exchange, not even exist on their

Comment: "two ways site permission" - can you explain what that is?

Comment: can you post screenshot, maybe it will be more understandable.

Comment: @Danilo , I did attached

Comment: But you posted image with user only once shown. Where is the 2nd time same user is displayed?

Comment: The high lighted one has no reference . We don't know this person and how it comes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the user permissions and re-grant permissions to the user.

Comment: before we are going to remove, do you have any idea why that happened ?